# JS Regex Get Values Between Two Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with a whole bunch of dynamic content and I need to get the hex colors out of the string.

```
<div class=''>2014-02-01</div>
<div class='' style='color: #0b62a4'>
   Company 1:
   $0
</div>
<div class='' style='color: #7A92A3'>
   Company 2:
   $4
</div>
```

I want to get all of the hex colors in an array in js. In js how can i use regex to get all of the hex colors between "#" and "'"? Thanks in advanced!

sample code:

```
<script>
    var colors = getStringBetween(content,"#","'");
</script>
```

Comment: Any attempts made yourself yet?

Comment: Why rely on regex instead of DOM methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color Hexcode can be 3 digits or 6 digits

RegEx you need is

```
/(#[0-9A-F]{6})|(#[0-9A-F]{3})/gi
```

Here is the [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kW5mG2)

**Code**

```
var getAllColors = function(content) {
    return content.match(/(#[0-9A-F]{6})|(#[0-9A-F]{3})/gi)
}

var str = "<div class=''>2014-02-01</div><div class=''style='color: #0b62a4'>Company 1:$0</div><div class=''style='color: #7A92A3'>Company 2:$4</div><div class=''style='color: #7A3'>Company 2:$4</div>"

getAllColors(str)
//output ["#0b62a4", "#7A92A3", "#7A3"]
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting - you gave me +125, +100 for crossing 200 :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex similar to the following

```
var rgbHex = /#([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])/gi
```

with the `str.match` function to extract the list of matches

```
var colors = content.match(rgbHex);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is perfectly fine, but it won't go cross multiline, and the match function will return more than you want to iterate over (parenthesis sets will each show in the result)

try `.match(/\#[0-9a-fA-F]+?\'/gm):`

hit f12 and run this for example

```
("<div class=''>2014-02-01</div>"+
"<div class='' style='color: #0b62a4'>"+
   "Company 1:"+
   "$0"+
"</div>"+
"<div class='' style='color: #7A92A3'>"+
   "Company 2:"+
   "$4"+
"</div> ").match(/\#[0-9a-fA-F]+?\'/gm)
```

Comment: Answers change position, so 'The answer above' may be tomorrow's 'answer below'.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ug73K/1/

```
string=document.body.innerHTML;

matches=string.match(/#[0-9A-Za-z]{6}/g);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't catch any 3 digit hex codes (example: `#abc`).

Comment: {3,6} says 3-6, which works fine, but also matches 4 and 5 digit hex codes. Honestly, I don't think that will be a problem. If you look at mine, it's pretty lax and matches any series of digits after a # sign.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple function that returns an array of 6 digit hex numbers without the # character prepended. It will also auto expand any 3 digit hex codes present (example: #abc = aabbcc).

```
function getHex(str){
    var rHex = /#[\da-f]+/ig;
    var matches = str.match(rHex) || [];

    var i = matches.length;
    while(i--){
        var match = matches[i].slice(1);

        if(match.length == 3){
            var expand = '';

            expand += match[0] + match[0];
            expand += match[1] + match[1];
            expand += match[2] + match[2];

            match = expand;
        }

        matches[i] = match;
    }
    return matches;
}
```